# How to inner join two or more tables together in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query i want to the results should get updated in my customer_info table. I do know have any relation ships between the table, however i have to use inner join to run queries. Please help.

current tags table

```
_reader_ID_|__tag_no__|__area |_maxtime_____
           |          |       |
```

Tag_logs table

```
reader_ID_|__tag_no__|timestamp___
          |          |
```

Aisle_info table

```
reader_ID_|_area_|
          |      |
```

customer_info table

```
name_|__email__|__reader_id |_tag_no|_area|_maxtime_
     |         |            |       |     |
```

```
INSERT INTO customer_info
SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID, tag_no, aisle_info.area, customer_info.name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID AND customer_info INNER JOIN current_tags ON customer_info.name = customer_info.name 
WHERE tag_no = 3222813112261
```

> 1052 - Column 'tag_no' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You should add the table name when a column is present in more then a table  so assuming that tag_no is present in tag_logs table  try tag_logs.tag_no

```
INSERT INTO customer_info
SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID
    , tag_logs.tag_no
    , aisle_info.area
    , customer_info.name
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp)
    ,MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME 
FROM tag_logs 
INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID 
    AND customer_info 
INNER JOIN current_tags ON customer_info.name = customer_info.name 
WHERE tag_logs.tag_no = 3222813112261
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just tried that method but i got this error #1054 - Unknown column 'customer_info.name' in 'field list'

Comment: your answer is giving me this error #1054 - Unknown column 'customer_info.name' in 'field list' How do i fix this?

Comment: the column  `customer_info.name` is in your query  be sure for eaxct column name 
 ...Your column is `name` or `name_`  with inderscore ...or somthings others  you should use proper name ever  ..